Odoo modue Event Registration duplicate key value violates unique constraint "utm_medium_unique_name"
Using the module Event (website_event_sale), there is an error occuring for some (few) of the customers in front office, when they click on the REGISTER-button that bring to the cart:
ERROR xxxxx-oerp-master-1178741 odoo.sql_db: bad query: 
INSERT INTO "utm_medium" (
"active", "create_date", "create_uid", "name",
 "write_date", "write_uid"
) 
VALUES (
true, '2024-10-30 14:48:16.373602', 1, 'email', 
'2024-10-30 14:48:16.373602', 1
) RETURNING "id"

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "utm_medium_unique_name"

DETAIL: Key (name)=(email) already exists.

WARNING xxxxxx-1178741 odoo.http: L'opération ne peut pas être terminée : Le nom doit être unique

POST /event/initiation-au-3eme-degre-reiki-shinpiden-2024-11-02-2024-11-03-2997/registration/newdirecttocart HTTP/1.0" 400 - 77 0.088 0.093



It seems that, during the creation of a new registration via front-office, odoo wants to create a new value in the utm.medium model... but while creating this new value 'email', odoo triggers the UNIQUE constrainst (probably because the value 'Email' already exist in this model).
My question: why does odoo does not check wether this value already exist before trying to create it...and how to fix it ?
addons/event_sale > model: event.registration:
class EventRegistration(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'event.registration'
    # ...
    # ...
    utm_medium_id = fields.Many2one(compute='_compute_utm_medium_id', readonly=False,
        store=True, ondelete="set null")

    @api.depends('sale_order_id')
    def _compute_utm_medium_id(self):
        for registration in self:
            if registration.sale_order_id.medium_id:
                registration.utm_medium_id = registration.sale_order_id.medium_id
            elif not registration.utm_medium_id:
                registration.utm_medium_id = False



addons/utm > model: utm.medium:
class UtmMedium(models.Model):
    _name = 'utm.medium'
    _description = 'UTM Medium'
    _order = 'name'

    name = fields.Char(string='Medium Name', required=True, translate=False)
    active = fields.Boolean(default=True)

    _sql_constraints = [
        ('unique_name', 'UNIQUE(name)', 'The name must be unique'),
    ]

    @api.model_create_multi
    def create(self, vals_list):
        new_names = self.env['utm.mixin']._get_unique_names(self._name, [vals.get('name') for vals in vals_list])
        for vals, new_name in zip(vals_list, new_names):
            vals['name'] = new_name
        return super().create(vals_list)


I have found a kind of solution (while expecting a better one), to prevent this kind of error. I have override the def compute of the corresponding field in model event.registration (and set the field value to False as it s not a mandatory field):

class EventRegistration(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'event.registration'

    @api.depends('sale_order_id')
    def _compute_utm_medium_id(self):
        for registration in self:
            registration.utm_medium_id = False

